# Usage of verb “top, bring”

Tags: verbs

> This place tops it bringing Japan’s famed hospitality to shame and to
> the drains.

How do I interpret this sentence that  I found on google maps online review about a restaurant

I suppose that “top” means verb.

I understood what this sentence meant, but I couldn’t make out what this sentence structure was.

Please tell me…

Comment: Hi Zen.  Please tell us exactly where you read this.   If you can provide a link that helps.  The punctuation seems odd and phrasing of "to the drains" is also strange.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I found this sentence on google maps online review about a restaurant(so it might be an automatically translation, but I remembered it was not). I cannot find this review anymore, maybe it has been  removed. I’m sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The structure is

> [This place]  Noun phrase, subject of sentence
>
> [tops] verb (meaning "be better" or "be more"
>
> [it] pronoun, object of verb.
>
> [bringing ...] participle phrase, describing how this place "tops it".

However the participle phrase is not grammatically correct.

To "top" can be used is positive or negative contexts:

> I've had good fish and chips, but the restaurant in Brighton tops it.

This means the fish and chips at the restaurant in Brighton is the best fish and chips.

> I slept at some dodgy hotels, but the hotel in New York tops them. The window was cracked and there was a literal family of cockroaches on the bed.

Here it means that the hotel was the worst.

I think the review is saying that "Although I have experienced bad hospitality, this place (in Japan) was the worst.  It brings shame on Japan. And it (metaphorically) takes Japan's reputation for hospitality and flushes it down the drain."

But the punctuation is wrong. You'd need a comma or something before  "bringing" and the expression is odd enough that really you would need to completely rewrite the participle phrase.

> ..., bringing shame on Japan and ruining its reputation for hospitality.

Random short comments on google maps is not the best place to look for well crafted and structured sentences!

Comment: Thank you for your kindness. I’ve really understood what you said. I couldn’t judge whether those sentences are correct or not, so I questioned.

Answer (score 1):

> This place tops it bringing Japan’s famed hospitality to shame and to the drains.

I cannot find reference on the use of *to the drains* in such context.  The author may have wanted to say **down the drain**, which is described in [Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/down-the-drain):

> down the drain
> PHRASE
> If you say that something is going down the drain, you mean that it is being destroyed or wasted.

> This place tops it bringing Japan’s famed hospitality to shame and **down the drain**.

In our example, *tops* is a verb and takes the following meaning in [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/top)

> top verb (BEST)

[ T ]

> to do, pay, etc. more or better than anyone else:
> She topped my suggestion with an even better one of her own.

Our example suggests that *This place* in Japan performs the **worst** in hospitality.

The phrase introduced by the present participle *bringing* is a participial phrase, and it describes *This place*.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, I didn’t know “down the drains” is favorable. And Google N-gram seems to be very useful. I misunderstood, “top ( that) it brings[bringing is wrong]…”, bringing is not a participial phrase. I appreciate your kindness.